# Set up wired/wireless connection between computers without network

Tags: windows-7, networking, laptop

I have two laptops that I need to set up a basic connection between. Let me describe them:

**Laptop A**: Windows 7 Secured Laptop where I cannot install anything. Uses locked down VPN and doesn't connect to the internet. I cannot connect to anything network wise outside of the VPN, even if I use a crossover cable do to security.

I can plug in and use any device that doesn't require an installation to use or has built in drivers for said device (USB flash drive, etc.)

I can also run programs that are self-contained in which all resources for said program are in the folder of the program or uses built-in resources (.NET 4.0 or built in DLLs).

I wish not to circumvent any security on this system.

**Laptop B**: Windows 8 Developer laptop in which I have full control over. If I have to make changes to a system I wish to do it only on this laptop.

So, what I want is certain folders/files from Laptop B immediately available to Laptop A. The ideal situation for me, but I haven't figured it out yet, is to have Laptop B available to Laptop A simply as an external drive in which file resources from Laptop B are instantly available.

Any ideas? I am trying to avoid using the flash drive just to copy files over from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas to try, but they might be limited by system policies on Laptop A.

1. Acquire a *crossover* ethernet cable, connect the laptops, and turn on file sharing on Laptop B, share selected folders on Laptop B, browse to the folders on Laptop A using UNC file paths (e.g., \LaptopA\mySharedFolder).
2. With the crossover cable installed, run a mini web server on Laptop B and web-browse files on Laptop B (e.g., \LaptopA_or_IpAddress:8000\path). Python can be easily used for a mini web server (web search `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for examples).
3. If both laptops have bluetooth, you can turn it on both, have one discover the other, and transfer individual files through their respective interfaces.